# How to change array with collection laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel project 
I have multi level categories in my project and I create a method to get all products of each category and its children so the problem is that
products are array and I have many problems with it e.g pagination , where() , orderBy and ...

I want to change my method to better thing that I can use it for above problems

btw I have a method name products() that gives all products of category

here is my method that gives me array of products

```
public function getAllCategoriesProducts($cat_id){
  $allProducts = [];
  foreach(ProductCategory::find($cat_id)->products()->get() as $product){
    $allProducts[] = $product;
  }
  foreach(ProductCategory::find($cat_id)->children()->get() as $subCategory){
    if($subCategory->children()->exists()){
      foreach($subCategory->children()->get() as $subSubCategory){
        foreach($subSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
        $allProducts[] = $product;
        }
      }
      if($subSubCategory->children()->exists()){
        foreach($subSubCategory->children()->get() as $subSubSubCategory){
          foreach($subSubSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
          $allProducts[] = $product;
          }
          if($subSubSubCategory->children()->exists()){
            foreach($subSubSubCategory->children()->get() as $subSubSubSubCategory){
              foreach($subSubSubSubCategory->products()->get() as $product){
              $allProducts[] = $product;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $allProducts;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using relationship of Laravel eloquent?

Comment: why did you use a array? Instead of using a array you can use a `collection`

Comment: @diego when I want to use it I use collect() and it changes to collection but does not work well

Comment: I'm trying to correct your code but I don't understand what `if($subSubCategory->children()->exists())`because the variable `$subSubCategory` doesn't exist

Comment: @diego it exists it is the second level of sub category

Comment: @hassankhosro there is that within this loop `foreach($subCategory->children()->get() as $subSubCategory)`. So, it doesn't exist externally

Comment: @diego  it works well now and gives me array of products of each sub category

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look, its better way to do this.
https://serversideup.net/eloquent-parent-child-relationship-laravel/